# Chrome throwing Missing parameters in request. Send user_name, email, password error

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am trying to authenticate a user using an API. the login API is working fine. If a person is not registered it prints the message to register first. But the register function is not working. I am  getting response code 400 on hitting the register API.

It shows the following message:

```
Missing parameters in request. Send user_name, email, password
```

I am not able to understand where am i going wrong. Ideally it should hit the API and create a new user and then should redirect to next page.

here is my code for sign up function

```
$(".form-item.sign-up .btn").click(
  async () => {
    get_email = document.getElementById("email_box2").value;
    get_password = document.getElementById("password2").value;
    get_username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    console.log(get_email, get_password, get_username);
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:81/traveliobot/api/v1/auth/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': get_email,
        'password': get_password,
        'username': get_username
      }) // string or object

    });
    const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
    response_code = myJson.responseCode
    console.log(response_code)
    if (response_code == '0') {
      user_id = myJson.user_id;
      console.log(user_id)
      linkLocation = 'chat_index.html';
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("user_id", user_id);
      $("body").fadeOut(1500, redirect_page)
    } else {
      console.log(myJson.responseDesc)
    }
  }
);

function redirect_page() {
  window.location = linkLocation;
  widn
}
```

login function:

```
$(".form-item.log-in .btn").click(
  async () => {
    get_email = document.getElementById("email_box1").value;
    get_password = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:81/traveliobot/api/v1/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': get_email,
        'password': get_password
      }) // string or object

    });
    const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
    response_code = myJson.responseCode
    console.log(response_code)
    if (response_code == '0') {
      user_id = myJson.user_id;
      console.log(user_id)
      linkLocation = 'chatbot_index.html';
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("user_id", user_id);
      $("body").fadeOut(1500, redirect_page)
    } else {
      console.log(myJson.responseDesc)
    }
  }
);

function redirect_page() {
  window.location = linkLocation;
  widn
}
```

html file:

```
<div class="container-form">
                <div class="form-item log-in">
                    <div class="table">
                        <div class="table-cell">
                            <input name="Username" placeholder="Email" type="text" id="email_box1" /><input name="Password"
                                placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password1" />
                            <div class="btn">
                                Log in
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item sign-up">
                    <div class="table">
                        <div class="table-cell">
                            <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" id="email_box2" />
                            <input name="Username" placeholder="Username"type="text" id="username" />
                            <input name="Password" placeholder="Password" type="Password" id="password2" />
                            <div class="btn">
                                Sign up
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `username` instead of `user_name` in the JSON payload of the register API call.